# Why is k-medians typically used with Manhattan rather than Euclidean distance?

Tags: clustering, optimization, k-means, distance-functions

K-medians is typically used with Manhattan distance rather than Euclidean distance. Why is this?

Comment: Do you have a source for this extraordinary claim?

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=IfTpAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=k+medians+manhattan&source=bl&ots=33TM6Vs3mJ&sig=2KDU5EnZlUGGKjilfY8oM9XPCCI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ceFjVIOfBMW1oQTVxoKgDg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=k%20medians%20manhattan&f=false

Comment: At "When folks ..."

Comment: One of the **benefit** of using PAM (K median/K means are not algorithms) is that we can use arbitrary distance metric. That doesn't mean we **need** to use Manhattan distance.

Comment: So, in a way, K median might be used instead of K means when we know Manhattan distance is suitable in our problem. Because, I don't think LLyods algorithm for K means is guaranteed to converge for Manhattan distance. But there might be other reasons for choosing K medoids too.

Comment: Yes, I know we don't need to use the Manhattan distance. I just don't understand the intuition behind why Manhattan distance is more suitable for K medians.

Answer (score 3):

The mean is a **least squares** estimator of location. It is appropriate to use with *squared* deviations (i.e. squared Euclidean distance, k-means algorithm)

The median is the best **absolute deviation** estimator or location. It is appropriate to use with *absolute* deviations (i.e. Manhattan distance, k-medians algorithm)

The medoid (c.f. PAM) is a smallest-distance estimator, it works with arbitrary distances. (K-medoids algorithm = PAM).